# PostgreSQL - additional foreign key constraints for authorization

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, authorization

I am trying to configure a foreign key that requires that a particular column on each side of the relationship be identical. This is to ensure that "ownership" integrity is enforced at the database level.

That may be unclear, but I think that an example will make it more clear what I am asking:

Consider a database with a table called `user_account`, which represents user accounts. Users of the app can create `books` and `chapters`, which are both represented as individual tables in the database.

Each `chapter` and `book` has a foreign key to the `user_account` – the account that created and "owns" that piece of data. The idea here is that users should only be able to modify their own books and chapters.

A snippet of the `book` table might look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
  user_account_id uuid,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_account_id) REFERENCES user_account(id)
);
```

Additionally, each `chapter` must have an associated `book`. Consider this snippet of the `chapter` table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE chapter (
  user_account_id uuid,
  book_id uuid,

  FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES book(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_account_id) REFERENCES user_account(id)
);
```

A problem with this foreign key is that it allows a user to create a chapter that is associated with *someone else's* book, unless I guard against this in app code.

If it must be enforced at the application layer, then that is OK. However, this seems like something that PostgreSQL might be able to enforce. Is there a way to require that the `book_id` of a given `chapter` references a `book` with the same `user_account_id` as the `chapter`?

[This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153392/why-do-composite-foreign-keys-need-a-separate-unique-constraint) seems similar to what I am asking, but an alternative solution is not provided in detail in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using the answers [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153392/why-do-composite-foreign-keys-need-a-separate-unique-constraint) and two PostgreSQL features:

1. Constraints
2. Composite foreign keys

First, in the `books` table, add a CONSTRAINT:

```
UNIQUE (id, user_account_id)
```

This lets PostgreSQL know that the combination of these two columns is unique across the entire table. Although the `user_account_id` may be duplicated, we know that the `id` is always unique. Therefore, the ID paired with anything else is also guaranteed to be unique (this is what the poster of the referenced question is referring to).

Moving on, setting up this constraint allows you to use [a composite foreign key](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) on the `chapters` table:

```
FOREIGN KEY (asset_id, user_account_id) REFERENCES asset(id, user_account_id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
```

This seems to be working as expected.